# Python Docker Container Will Not Start Receive This Error: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, mysql, docker, docker-compose, mysql-connector

I have a project that uses Docker, Python, MySQL, MySQL Connector, and Grafana.  When I am not using docker, I am able to run the Python Program and it sends data to MySQL as it should.  I'm able to create the containers.  The Grafana and MySQL containers stay running but the Python one shuts down due to a connection error. My educated guess is it is because Python is starting before MySQL, but I'm not sure how I would fix this or test my theory.

My project consists of four files.  They are Docker-Compose.yml, Dockerfile, requirements.txt, and startTemp.py. Below is my code
Thanks in advance.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python", "startTemp.py"]
```

Requirement.txt:

```
mysql-connector-python==8.0.25
```

Docker-Compose.yml

```
version:"3"
services:
    grafana:
        image:grafana/grafana
        container_name: grafana
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
        networks:
            - temperature_network
        volumes:
            - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
        depends_on:
            - mysql

    mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
    
        networks: 
            - temperature_network
        volumes:
            - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
        
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        depends_on:
            - python

    python:
        build: .
        container_name: python
        networks:
            - temperature_network

networks:
    temperature_network:
volumes:
    grafana_data:
    mysql_data:
```

startTemp.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

import random   
import time 
from time import localtime, strftime




DB_NAME = 'temperature'

TABLES = {}

TABLES['chamber_probe_green'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `chamber_probe_green`("
    "   `id` INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "   `time` TIME NOT NULL,"
    "   `temp` FLOAT NOT NULL,"
    "   PRIMARY KEY (ID)"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")



TABLES['chamber_probe_blue'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `chamber_probe_blue`("
    "   `id` INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "   `time` TIME NOT NULL,"
    "   `temp` FLOAT NOT NULL,"
    "   PRIMARY KEY (ID)"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")



TABLES['food_probe_yellow'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `food_probe_yellow`("
    "   `id` INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "   `time` TIME NOT NULL,"
    "   `temp` FLOAT NOT NULL,"
    "   PRIMARY KEY (ID)"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")



TABLES['food_probe_red'] = (
    "CREATE TABLE `food_probe_red`("
    "   `id` INT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
    "   `time` TIME NOT NULL,"
    "   `temp` FLOAT NOT NULL,"
    "   PRIMARY KEY (ID)"
    ") ENGINE=InnoDB")


clock = strftime("%I:%M", localtime())

data = "{:.2f}".format(random.random()*100)


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
cursor = cnx.cursor()

def create_database(cursor):
    try:
        cursor.execute(
            "CREATE DATABASE {} DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 
'utf8'".format(DB_NAME))
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Failed creating database: {}".format(err))
        exit(1)
try:
    cursor.execute("USE {}".format(DB_NAME))
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print("Database {} does not exist.".format(DB_NAME))
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        create_database(cursor)
        print("Database {} created successfully.".format(DB_NAME))
        cnx.database = DB_NAME
    else:
        print(err)
        exit(1)

for table_name in TABLES:
    table_description = TABLES[table_name]
    try:
        print("Creating table {}: ".format(table_name), end=' ')
        cursor.execute(table_description)
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_TABLE_EXISTS_ERROR:
            print("Already exists.")
        else:
            print(err.msg)
    else:
        print("OK")




def insertData():

    while(True):

        AddDataBlue = ("INSERT INTO chamber_probe_blue "
                        "(time, temp)"
                        "VALUES (%s, %s)") 

        AddDataGreen = ("INSERT INTO chamber_probe_green "
                        "(time, temp)"
                        "VALUES (%s, %s)") 

        AddDataYellow = ("INSERT INTO food_probe_yellow "
                        "(time, temp)"
                        "VALUES (%s, %s)") 

        AddDataRed = ("INSERT INTO chamber_probe_blue "
                        "(time, temp)"
                        "VALUES (%s, %s)") 
    
        dataBlue = (clock, data)

        dataGreen = (clock, data)

        dataYellow = (clock, data)

        dataRed = (clock, data)
        print("Adding Blue Data")
        cursor.execute(AddDataBlue, dataBlue)
        print("Adding Green Data")
        cursor.execute(AddDataGreen, dataGreen)
        print("Adding Yellow Data")
        cursor.execute(AddDataYellow, dataYellow)
        print("Adding Red ddata")
        cursor.execute(AddDataRed, dataRed)

        cnx.commit()

        time.sleep(2)

insertData()

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Error listed in Docker logs:

```
python | File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 574, in open_connection

python | self.sock.connect(sockaddr)

python | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: I thought I added images not links not sure what I did wrong.  I apologize for the annoyance.

Comment: All **relevant** code has to be added to the **question itself**. Your project story is less relevant BTW. Stay focused on the problem.

Comment: Thank you.  Ill fix this.

Comment: Where do you configure the database location?  If the problem is that the application is starting before the database (and this does happen), if you wait 60 seconds and run `docker-compose up -d` again, does it work the second time?

Comment: `cnx = mysql.connector.connect(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)` <= this is certainly the cause of your problem since `xxxxxxxxxx` is not a correct parameter for this function. More seriously, how do you expect anyone to help you on a connection refused error if you hide the details of your db connection, more specifically the hostname you are using?

Comment: David, I will have to try that.  Zeitounator, the only thing that was left out was the user and the password for login purposes.  Where it worked without putting it in the container I did not feel this was the issue. I also didn't feel it was very secure to share my username and password.